# error in converting datetime from character string in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm facing problems in passing the date parameters.

I'm getting the error

> *Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.*

My stored procedure is the below, please let me know what to do,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WEEKLY_REPORT_PROC](
    @START_DATE DATETIME,
    @END_DATE     DATETIME,@PRACTISE_NAME NVARCHAR(MAX))--,
    -- @D1 DECIMAL(5,2),
    -- @D2 DECIMAL(5,2),
    -- @D3 DECIMAL(5,2),
    -- @D4 DECIMAL(5,2),
    -- @D5 DECIMAL(5,2),
    -- @D6 DECIMAL(5,2),
    -- @D7 DECIMAL(5,2))
AS 
BEGIN


EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @QUERY

DECLARE CP_DETAILS CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM #TEMP

OPEN CP_DETAILS
FETCH NEXT FROM CP_DETAILS INTO     @RESOURCE_NAME,@DAY1,@DAY2,@DAY3,@DAY4,@DAY5,@DAY6,@DAY7,@UTILIZATION

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS =0)
BEGIN
    SET @UTILIZATION = dbo.UTILIZATION(@START_DATE,@END_DATE,@DAY1,                                         @DAY2,@DAY3,@DAY4,@DAY5,@DAY6,@DAY7)
    --INSERT INTO @WEEKLY_REPORT_DETAILS_INFORMATION VALUES(@RESOURCE_NAME,
    --          @DAY1,@DAY2,@DAY3,@DAY4,@DAY5,@DAY6,@DAY7,@UTILIZATION)
    UPDATE #TEMP SET UTILIZATION = @UTILIZATION WHERE RESOURCE_NAME=@RESOURCE_NAME

    FETCH NEXT FROM CP_DETAILS INTO @RESOURCE_NAME,@DAY1,@DAY2,@DAY3,@DAY4,@DAY5,@DAY6,@DAY7
END
CLOSE CP_DETAILS
DEALLOCATE CP_DETAILS
SELECT * FROM #TEMP
--SELECT DBO.RETRIEVE(@QUERY) AS QUERY FROM CP_DETAILS
PRINT @QUERY
DROP TABLE #TEMP
RETURN 
END 
END
```

In middle I use one user-defined function `utilization`, and passing the parameters as date fields

Comment: so... what values are you passing into your variables?

Comment: @RandomUs1r the execution is  EXEC WEEKLY_REPORT_PROC'2012-03-31' ,'2012-04-06','CS'

Comment: Have you tried `EXEC WEEKLY_REPORT_PROC '20120331' ,'20120406','CS'`? For [datetime constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx), `YYYYMMDD` is always interpreted consistently but `YYYY-MM-DD` may not be. But your code is incomplete because you haven't shown the dynamic SQL part: what is `@QUERY` and where does it come from? As a complete guess, your dynamic SQL is wrong but it's hard to say without more information. And have you added some debugging code to identify exactly where the error occurs?

Comment: Both '2012-03-31' and '2012-04-06' should not have any problem converting to datetime. If the formatting is correct, perhaps you're sending some incorrect values... ie. 2012-02-30.

Answer (score -1):

Try...

```
DECLARE @startdate varchar(30), @enddate varchar(30)

SET @startdate = CONVERT(varchar(10), '2012-03-31', 101)
SET @enddate = CONVERT(varchar(10),'2012-04-06', 101)


EXEC WEEKLY_REPORT_PROC @startdate, @enddate,'CS'
```

Your problem is what you're passing in: YYY-MM-dd is not going to get converted by SQL into a datetime automatically like 'MM/dd/YYYY', converting it to 101 format should resolve your issue.

Comment: You cannot have convert there.

Comment: Fixed, concepts more or less the same, 2012-04-05 doesn't have trouble converting to a datetime, but MM/dd/YYYY auto convert, so if you're going to pass varchars, it has to be MM/dd/YYYY.  If OP has application code that sets the format, he'd need to do it there.